# Text in a QGraphicsScene

Tags: text, qgraphicsview

How to write text in a certain cordinate in QGraphicsScene? I was trying to do like this, but with no success. Text has black borders but inside the letters it is white, and I can't make it black.

```
    QPainterPath path;

    QFont font;
    font.setPixelSize(50);

    path.addText(100, 50, font,  tr("Hello World!!!"));
    path.setFillRule();

    m_graphScen->addPath(path);
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Variant 1 (not a good one):

```
QFont font;
font.setPixelSize(10);
font.setBold(false);
font.setFamily("Calibri");

path.addText(100, 50, font,  "Hello World!!");

m_graphScen->addPath(path, QPen(QBrush(Qt::black), 1), QBrush(Qt::black));
```

Variant 2 (fine version):

```
QGraphicsTextItem * io = new QGraphicsTextItem;
io->setPos(150,70);
io->setPlainText("Barev");

m_graphScen->addItem(io);
```