# Qt - Real time drawing

Tags: c++, qt, real-time

I  want to show a car's path in a window in real time, how to do that, and what classes I have to use. Is there anything like drawing area, in Qt.

Any Help will be appreciated.

Comment: See this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298016/how-to-use-qt-graphic-view-for-drawing/3321888#3321888). This is almost the same question.

Comment: Question is not clear! Do you want to draw a path for the car which it should pass? Or do you have a car which is moving and you want to draw the path of its movement? If you want to do the second then imagine that the car is acting like a mouse pointer and see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to read up on [QGraphicsview](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/graphicsview.html). There are several helpful examples that show every bit of what functionality is present here. The implementation itself... I guess it's just a bunch of `QLine`s on a `QGraphicsScene`. The realtime part is handled by calling repaint or paintevent or whatever it's called periodically, or setting up a complex animation.

Answer (score 0):

The [Qwt](http://qwt.sf.net) library on top of Qt is pretty good for this.

Comment: I have written several real-time data plotters with it, and the new code is maybe 200 lines. Works for me, YMMV.

Comment: The question (as I read it) is not about a plot (I could be mistaken), it is about a car's path, which I interpreted as a physical line being drawn behind a (2D) car moving across the scene.

Comment: @rubenvb
  Ya, you got it. I want to put pixel by pixel in a map(or any image type like jpeg,png,etc), or an empty map or in a newly created image.